# Machine reboots while Installing Ubuntu desktop 12.10 on Windows 7 platform from USB

Tags: installation

I downloaded Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.4 and Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 yesterday. I used a blank 4GB pendrive and burned the Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 ISO file on it using the Universal-USB-Installer.

I have a Windows 7 Professional OS running on 3GB RAM (Intel Core 2 Duo processor). I have sufficient hard disk space on my c drive (around 70-80GB free).

So I thought that I should be able to install Ubuntu easily.

I went to my BIOS settings and changed the boot order and put the USB option at the top. And then I rebooted my machine. I get into the installer. I even get to the screen where you get to decide to install Ubuntu within your windows. But as soon as I click continue on that screen, my machine reboots. And I cannot understand why this should happen.

I tried using a Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.01 ISO file instead. I got the same results.

Comment: did u got any solution here?

Comment: I think the Ubuntu 12.10 iso file downloaded is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

First when you download .iso file, You should [check md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

If md5sum isn't Correct then you have corrupted .iso file and you have to download it again and make USB or burn disk. If md5sum is correct than there are no chances of occuring such problems.

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced similar issue. I am not sure if it is to do with my hardware as I know my laptop has been having such issues but this was just too frequent. I managed to install by not enabling download 3rd party software and net enabled. This made the installation faster I guess but it did reboot before completing the installation. I am just glad the grub was in place otherwise I would be stranded in my last attempt (I made at least half a dozen attempts to install today).

I suspect that it is something to do with network. Now each time I try to update software it is rebooting without giving me a chance. Hoping this is fixed soon if a problem with the image. This is my work laptop and I need to get it up and running soon. Reason for moving from 12.04 was that it was painful in many ways. Hoping this release is better.